# Create a query string with or condition

Tags: java, sql, conditional-statements

I create a jpql query with a string

```
    StringBuilder stringQuery = new StringBuilder();

    stringQuery.append("select school from School school where   ");

    if(schooSearch.name()!=null && !schooSearch.name()){

        stringQuery.append(" contains( ");
        stringQuery.append("school.name, ");
        stringQuery.append(":name");
        stringQuery.append(" ) > 0 ");
    }

    if(schooSearch.adr()!=null && !schooSearch.adr().isEmpty()){

        stringQuery.append(" or ");
        stringQuery.append(" school.adr like  ");
        stringQuery.append(":adr");

    }
```

All conditions use **or**, i have many other fields.

What is the way to avoid to check for every condition if it's the first field and we need a where

Comment: Not sure it's the best solution, but I often see people write dynamic queries as `SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1=2`. Then all of your additional clauses could have `OR`s, regardless of order. (Would be `WHERE 1=1` for `AND`s)

Comment: You could use "if .... else if .. else if ...."

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a flexible prepared statement:

```
select school
from School school
where (school.name LIKE :name OR :name IS NULL) AND
      (school.adr LIKE :adr OR :adr IS NULL)
```

Each condition in the `WHERE` clause will evaluate to true and no-op should the bound parameter be null.  Note that JPA does not have any `contains()` function, so instead you should bind `%some name%` to the `:name` parameter.